# How can i make double press back to close my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have startActivity and HomeScreen activity. HomeScreen activity appears after startActivity. I want to implement double click back to close the application. I tried this code, but after the app is closed, it immediately reopens again or just returns to startActivity.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Нажмите ещё раз что бы закрыть приложение", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: can you post your startActivity class code?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This is not normal android behavior and is more likely to annoy users than anything else.  But the reason you're having problems is that super.onBackPressed doesn't exit an application-  it finishes an Activity.  So it will take you back to whatever is behind it on the stack.  If you want to not have startActivity in your stack (so you can't go back to it), it needs to have called finish() on itself after launching HomeActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is in some child activity (not in the main activity), then try replacing:

```java
super.onBackPressed()
```

with:

```java
finishAffinity()
```

Since according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()):

> The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

calling `super.onBackPressed()` will finish **current** activity - not the whole application. And probably this is the source of Your bugs, but I cannot know for sure, since You haven't provided us with broader context - more code.

So, on the other hand `finishAffinity()` *might* be the solution for You. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAffinity()) say:

> Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity.

This should finish all the activities.